# How to prove the following step in the proof of conditional entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I do not know how Eq. (2.58) is obtained from Eq. 2.57 in the following proof for conditional entropy. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I think we can even avoid this step but I am not sure.

Comment: Since the term inside the log does not depend on $x_{i+1},\dots, x_n$, you can pull this term in front of these sums, and then marginalize the distribution, i.e., use $\sum_{x_{i+1},\dots,x_n} p(x_1, \dots, x_n) = p(x_1, \dots, x_i)$.

Comment: @karakusc Thank you for your explanation